# Two forms, two models, one view ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, models

I'm trying to make two forms for two different models in the same view.

I have a model named category and a model named post.
Im trying to make a form for categories in the same view i have a form for posts.
The form for posts works fine, but when i'm trying to add the form for categories i get this error:
undefined method `model_name' for Category::ActiveRecord_Relation:Class

category.rb - model

> has_many :posts

post.rb - model

> has_many :categories

posts_controller

```
def index
@posts = new.Post
@categories = new.Category
end

def create
@posts = Post.create(post_params)
@posts.save
redirect_to :back
end

def create_cate
@categories = Categroy.create(categories_params)
@categroies.save
redirect_to :back
end
```

posts view - index.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@posts) do |f| %>
<%= f.text_field :title %>
<%= f.text_area :content %>
<%= f.submit %>
<% end %>

<%= form_for(@categories) do |f| %>
<%= f.text_field :name %>
<%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

routes.rb

```
resources :posts
resources :categories
root 'posts#index'
```

I have tried to search after if, but i can only find solutions for two models, one form.

Thanks in advance. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you say its in the index action:

```
def index
  @post = Post.new
  @category = Category.new
end
```

In your view:

```
<%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :title %>
  <%= f.text_area :content %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>

<%= form_for(@category) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This approach is wrong as per [Sandi's rule](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/sandi-metz-rules-for-developers) - *Controllers can instantiate only one object. Therefore, views can only know about one instance variable and views should only send messages to that object.*

Comment: @ArupRakshit Rules are to make you think twice, they are not here to prevent you from doing business

Comment: @apneadiving No.. That's not a good idea.. I am not feeling well with your approach.